# Does changing which table with joins is selected affect performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have 2 tables, receivers belongs to groups, lets assume that there are 1 million records on the receivers table and 100 on the groups

This query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM groups g
JOIN rxs r ON g.id=r.group_id
WHERE g.id IN (21, 80, 93)
```

Is equally functional to this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rxs r
JOIN groups g ON g.id=r.group_id
WHERE g.id IN (21, 80, 93)
```

Is there a benefit of using one over the other? if I need to join another 2 or 3 tables in my query, will it be better to select first from the smallest or the larges table?

Regards...

Comment: The optimizer decides the actual order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the answer is no, you should not try to optimize this yourself. The MySQL query optimizer will do that automatically. There's no reason to change the order of tables in your query, because it's not necessarily the order the tables will be joined anyway.

For an inner join — the type you show in your example query — it doesn't matter. Inner joins are commutative (like addition and multiplication in arithmetic), and the MySQL optimizer will reorder them automatically to improve the performance. You can use EXPLAIN to see a report of which order the optimizer will choose.

In rare cases, the optimizer's estimate isn't optimal, and it chooses the wrong table order. You can use `STRAIGHT_JOIN` to override this, and force the query to join tables in the order you specified them in your query. There are other join-related optimizer hints in MySQL 8.0. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-join-order for details.

Left and right outer joins are not commutative, and will not be reordered by the optimizer. But the order is significant to the result, so you should not reorder them either.

Comment: I think a `LEFT JOIN` will be turned into an `INNER JOIN` when there is nothing like `WHERE id IS NULL` to make a difference.

Comment: That's not correct.

Comment: `explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM canada AS c LEFT JOIN provinces AS p USING(province) WHERE p.abbrev = 'AB';` ...  Explain shows `p` as table 1.  Then `SHOW WARNINGS;` -->  `/* select#1 */ select count(0) AS `COUNT(*)` from `world`.`canada` `c` join `world`.`provinces` `p` where ((`world`.`c`.`province` = 'Alberta'))` -- Note the plain `join`.

Comment: Yes, if the WHERE clause has a condition on the outer table that requires it to be non-NULL, it does change the join. But I didn't infer that from your statement.